# JQuery Mobile: format autocomplete results

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working on a mobile option for an internal web application. I have an auto-select working on the PC side, but when viewing on the mobile side, the searched results just looks bad when displayed:
 [bad format http://www.rkrdevel.com/files/mobile_autoselect.png](http://www.rkrdevel.com/files/mobile_autoselect.png)

Optimally, I would like to have the list view look more like a drop list. When displayed on a phone, I understand that it may list below the keyboard but that is OK for now.

I use this same snippet of code on both my main site and also the mobile site. In order to determine if it a mobile device, I call a function I made called: check_mobile().

I found the autoselect code somewhere, but am not sure how to go about applying a format to the result set. Any help is appreciated.

html:

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <p>To find a customer, enter the Customer name, all lower case and no spaces. For example, bwi or t&r</p>
    <label for="Customer">Customer Name: </label>
    <input id="Customer" placeholder="Search"/>
    <div class="ui-widget" id="results" style="width: 600px; font-weight: bold; border-bottom: black;">Search Results: </div>
    <div data-theme="b" id="custData"  data-collapsed="true" data-role="collapsible"></div><!--class="ui-widget-content"-->
</div>
```

jquery autoselect function:

```
init: function(){
    $('#results').hide();
    $( "#Customer" ).val('');
    $( "#Customer" )
        // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
        .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        })
        .autocomplete({
            delay: 500,
            source: function( request, add ) {
                $.getJSON( cust.url+"?funct=1" , {term: cust.extractLast( request.term )}, function(data) {  
                    //create array for response objects  
                    var suggestions = [];  
                    //process response
                   for(var i =1, ii=data[0];i<=ii;i++){
                        suggestions.push(data[i].ABAN8 + ':' + $.trim(data[i].ABDC));
                    }  
                    //pass array to callback  
                    add(suggestions);
                });
            },
            search: function() {
                // custom minLength
                $( "#custData" ).hide();
                $('#results').hide();
                var term = cust.extractLast( this.value );
                if ( term.length < 2 ) {
                    cust.clearReportData();
                    return false;
                }
            },
            focus: function() {
                // prevent value inserted on focus
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                var terms = cust.split( this.value );
                // remove the current input
                terms.pop();
                // add the selected item
                terms.push( ui.item.value );
                // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                terms.push( "" );
                cust.getfulldetail(ui.item.value);
                return false;
            }
        })
        .focus();
},
```

Comment: what about using the [search filter bar](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/lists/lists-search.html)?

Comment: This is an AJAX selection. It searches a remote database as the user types

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of  autocomplete solutions for JQM, you will want to check out [JQM autocomplete](http://andymatthews.net/code/autocomplete/) or [this implementation](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2012/3/27/Example-of-Autocomplete-in-jQuery-Mobile).

Comment: i am looking JQM autocomplete search result should show over the div instead of pushing the div's down.can you help

Answer (score 0):

Specific problem here is that you forgot to add the css file to your solution, and the ordering matters, for example

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.css" />
```